# Preencher Select criando por append Javascript

Tags: javascript

Opa,

Possuo um botão para criação de alguns inputs, preciso preencher um select ao cria-lo com dados do bd, fiz assim, joguei numa variavel javascript os valores da consulta sql.

```
    foreach ($operadoras as $key => $value) {
      $val_operadoras = $val_operadoras.$value['id'].':'.$value['descricao'].';';
    }

    echo '
      <Script type="text/javascript">
        var opts = "'.$val_operadoras.'";
      </script>
    ';
```

Para o preenchimento do select fiz:

```
            function preenche_select()
            {

                opts = opts.split(';');
                var target = $(".id_operadora");
                $.each(opts, function(i, opt){
                  opt = opt.split(':');
                  target.append($('<option />').val(opt[0].trim()).text(opt[1].trim()));

                  document.getElementById("id_operadora").selectedIndex = "4";
                });
            }
```

Funciona apenas após criar o primeiro select, após isso, os selects são criados, mas, não são preenchidos.

Para criar os inputs estou chamando o append com este código:

```
    $('#add').live('click', function() { 
        addCampo();

        preenche_select();

    });
```

Comment: já debugou para ver se os dados realmente estão chegando ao código que gera os "options"?

Comment: ja dei um alert dentro da função preenche_lista: alert(opts );. Ele exibe as mensagens normalmente, mas, não preenche o select

Comment: no console imprimiu 'opts.split is not a function'

Comment: tem certeza que opts é uma string? isso aqui simula este erro do console: "var a = []; a.split(';');", certifique-se de que opts já não é um array.